# Images in MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net, blob

I have a blob column in my table. How do I insert an image into it and how do I retrieve it onto the picture-box on a windows form?
I am using visual studio IDE and VB.Net is the language

Comment: I don't think your question can be answered without at least some hint at the platform/technology/programming language you're using.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend that you don't do this. Store it as a file on the filesystem and put the filename in the database instead.

Comment: For the edification of myself and others, why is storing the image as a blog in the db a bad idea? Is this just a MySQL issue?

Comment: There are database engines out there that handle largish BLObs in a manner that doesn't hurt performance, but MySQL isn't one of them.

Answer (score 2):

If the image is located on your MySQL server host, you could use the [`LOAD_FILE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) command:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (image_col) VALUES(LOAD_FILE('/tmp/my_image.png'));
```

Make sure that the file is readable by MySQL, and also make sure that your MySQL user has the `FILE` privilege.

To grant the `FILE` privilege, log in as root and execute:

```
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'mysql_user'@'localhost';
```

In general I would also recommend storing the image on the filesystem, and just keeping the path in MySQL. However there are cases where this is useful.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Daniel. Currently am storing the path to the image but I want to be able to move the database and application to another computer without worrying about the path to the images.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is probably best if you store your images in the filesystem instead of the database.
2. but if you want to store in DB, you can just write the image data in as string and then retrieve it back as a string, set a header depending on the image type and then just flush it to the browser. (I did that using php and it worked)

Comment: Hope I will have to store my images in the file system. thank you Meosoft